# How to get sound duration on iOS when recording to .wav using Expo Audio?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to use Expo Audio to record sound on iOS as .wav format.

```
        ios: {
            extension: '.wav',
            audioQuality: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_IOS_AUDIO_QUALITY_HIGH,
            sampleRate: 44100,
            numberOfChannels: 1,
            bitRate: 128000,
            linearPCMBitDepth: 16,
            linearPCMIsBigEndian: false,
            linearPCMIsFloat: false,
        },
```

The recording works but when I retrieve the status, soundDuration is 0.

```
const status = await recording.getStatusAsync();
const soundDuration = status.durationMillis;
```

I found on Expo documentation:
"(note that in some cases, a media file's duration is readable on Android, but not on iOS)."

Can someone think of a workaround to get access to the sound duration?

Comment: Not at my desk atm to write out a proper answer, but calculating based on sample rate, channels, bitrate and bit depth should work. See this site for inspiration https://www.colincrawley.com/audio-duration-calculator/

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I simply get the time (`Date.now()`) at the beginning of the recording and compute the elapsed time at the end of the recording. It is hard to get a perfect result but it is enough to get to 0.1s precision.

Answer (score 0):

For me, durationMillis works on web and android, but the property name is playableDurationMillis on iOS. It's an annoying inconsistency, probably it'll be fixed in a later release.

Try something like this:
let duration = Platform.OS == 'ios' ? playbackStatus.playableDurationMillis : playbackStatus.durationMillis;